# Android animation like domino

Tags: android, animation, handler

I wanna make animation like domino effect.
but when i use animation xml and handler with for loop, it works together at the same time.

how can i make the domino effect animation such as start the animation for next button(tue) 100 milliseconds after the first button(mon) started?

my hanlder method here

```
private void startAnimation(final ArrayList<View> vArr)
{
    mon = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mon);
    tue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tue);
    wed = (Button)findViewById(R.id.wed);
    thu = (Button)findViewById(R.id.thu);
    fri = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fri);
    sat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sat);
    sun = (Button)findViewById(R.id.sun);

    final Button[] weekDayList = {mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun};

    Handler handler = new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            super.handleMessage(msg);

            switch (msg.what)
            {
                case 3:
                    for (int i = 0; i < weekDayList.length; i++)
                        weekDayList[i].startAnimation(buttonDown);

                    sendEmptyMessageDelayed(4, 100);

                    break;

                case 4:

                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    handler.sendEmptyMessage(3);
}
```

my animation xml here

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="100%"
    android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `ObjectAnimator` (since API 11) to do this and have the animations play sequentially by adding them all to an `AnimatorSet`.

```
  public void dominoAnimations() {
    ObjectAnimator monAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mon, "scaleY", 0f);
    ObjectAnimator tueAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tue, "scaleY", 0f);
    ObjectAnimator wedAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(wed, "scaleY", 0f);
    ObjectAnimator thuAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(thu, "scaleY", 0f);
    ObjectAnimator friAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fri, "scaleY", 0f);
    ObjectAnimator satAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(sat, "scaleY", 0f);
    ObjectAnimator sunAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(sun, "scaleY", 0f);

    AnimatorSet dominoes = new AnimatorSet();
    dominoes.playSequentially(
      monAnimation, tueAnimation, wedAnimation,
      thuAnimation, friAnimation, satAnimation, sunAnimation
    );

    dominoes.setDuration(500);
    dominoes.start();
  }
```

Comment: is it possible to add several options to ObjectAnimation?
i need to make it to disappear from top to bottom

Answer (score -1):

Set [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) to the animations. Use `onAnimationEnd()` to start the next animation.

Comment: but, what i want to do is start next animation while the first animation is working.